# http1.1 Keep-Alive without pipelining

Tags: http, webserver, http-1.1, embeddedwebserver

I'm implementing a server that is sending to the client a http keep-alive request but I would like that the client does not make pipelining requests. Is there any flag to tell client to not do multiple pipeline requests?

The keep-alive request seams to work but I don't want pipeline requests.

I would like a sequential request.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such flag.

FWIW, with pipelining the requests would still be sequential, you just can get more while still sending a response.